# Ajax call not happening immediately

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&t=412s) Youtube video where he explains Call Stack, Event loop in case of Async events like Ajax calls. He said JavaScript execution happens line by line. Let's execute a sample program:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    console.log(xhttp.responseText);
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", 'https://httpbin.org/get', true);
xhttp.send();

let i = 1;
while (i < 1000000000) {
  i++;
}

console.log(i);
```

So, my understanding is that the JS Engine will place Ajax call in the Call Stack and make Ajax Call. Since it takes some time, it will pass the callback to browser Web APIs and continue with rest of the code (while loop in our case). When Ajax call is done, Web Apis will put the callback in Task Queue. If the Call Stack is empty, Event Loop will place the Callback in Stack again and the callback gets executed. In our program, I intentionally made count large to make Event Loop wait for while loop to complete even though Ajax call is done. But When I ran the above program, the ajax call was made only after the loop is completed. Then what's the point in writing the ajax call before while loop. I am expecting Ajax call to fire immediately but print response after while loop is done. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: More to the point, what's the point of writing the while loop? :) `$.getJSON` is a function, which calls other functions, and eventually calls `XMLHTTPRequest.send` (maybe more recent versions of jQuery use `fetch`, I have no idea). In any case, if you want to measure something as sensitive as the event loop and the call stack, I would suggest not using jQuery or other libraries, but rather use code that's native to the browser.

Comment: LOL. I meant, writing ajax call after while loop will not change the overall program completion time. because the ajax call did not fire until the loop is completed. Why it did not fire? That's my question

Comment: What makes you think the Ajax call wasn’t  made until after the while loop completed? The *response* comes after, because it’s async, but there’s nothing in your code that records when the Ajax call itself was made.

Comment: I did not see HTTP call in network tab immediately. So, I assumed that call was not made

Answer (score -1):

I'll take a stab at answering this, if anyone else can explain it in more detail or can correct me, it'll be a good learning experience as well.

AJAX = Asynchronous Javascript And XML.
The name itself it stating that the function will be asynchronous.
According to the video that OP has linked, it seems that the explanation is very clear on what async codes is. Let's focus on the 'blocking' part of Javascript.

In your example, that AJAX call is added to the stack, but because it is an async function, it will not stop the next piece of code from running, your while loop.  The while loop is synchronous, so it WILL stop everything and let the while runs (which means your async is now blocked as well).

Since console.log() is a faster function than your AJAX result, it will print first and then followed by the result of the http call.

src: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&t=412s